# C# Build query OR condition

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have a test method which I'd like to return a query which should have OR condition based on input.

Let's say I input 3 statuses [New, IsProcessing, Done] and I want the query to return Payments which have either status New, IsProcessing or Done.

I try to build the query by adding .Where condition but it returns 0 row. I think it's doing the AND condition so no data as there's no payment having 3 statuses. Every single payment can have only 1 status.

```
public IQueryable<Payment> GetPaymentQuery(List<PaymentStatus> statuses)
    {
        IQueryable<Payment> query = _dbContext.Payment.AsQueryable();
        
        if (statuses != null && statuses.Any())
        {                
            if (statuses.Contains(PaymentStatus.New))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Status == PaymentStatus.New);
            }
            if (statuses.Contains(PaymentStatus.IsProcessing))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Status == PaymentStatus.IsProcessing);
            }
            if (statuses.Contains(PaymentStatus.Done))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Status == PaymentStatus.Done);
            }
        }

        return query;
    }
    
    
    public enum PaymentStatus{
        New, IsProcessing, Done, Cancelled
    }
```

Please can you advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid this by capturing it all in one `Where` clause using `Contains`:

```
public IQueryable<Payment> GetPaymentQuery(List<PaymentStatus> statuses)
{
    IQueryable<Payment> query = _dbContext.Payment.AsQueryable();

    if (statuses != null && statuses.Any())
    {
        var validStatuses = status.Where(x => x != PaymentStatus.Cancelled).Distinct();
        query = query.Where(x => validStatuses.Contains(x));      
    }

    return query;
}
```